# php can't open sqlite3 database

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have read a good bit on Stackoverflow, PHP Doc's, etc.  So far nothing helps me open my SQLite3 database in PHP 5.6.  This is my code snippet:

```
$db_file = "D:/Websites/Intranet/InetPub/wwwroot/WebDB/HamLog - SQLite/HamLog.SQLite";

// open database file

//$handle = sqlite_open($db) or die("Could not open database");      
//$db = new sqlite($db_file) or die("Could not open Dan's HamLog.SQLite");
//$db = new Database($db_file);
$this->db = new PDO("sqlite:.$db_file", NULL, NULL);
//$this->db = new SQLite3($db_file);
```

You can see I've tried a number of things that all just died at the open attempt line with an error code. The active try at least gives an error saying it is unable to open the database.  I can open the database using the sqlite console. Apparently in recent PHP releases, SQLite has been relegated to obscurity, by old references in the PHP documentation.  The best I've found is the SQLite library is now housed in PECL.  But then I read that its best to install PECL through PEAR.  At this point I need some help.  How do I open my SQLite database named: HamLog.SQLite in PHP?

Comment: what errors exactly do you get when using http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html ?

Comment: Likewise, how do you know connection is not made? Did you attempt a query? Is error raised?

Comment: I'll have to try the error reporting, but I know a connection wasn't made because the executable line following the connection line never executes in my debugger, and debugger never shows an error.  It just stops the debugger and returns to programming mode.  I use phpEd.

Comment: I am now getting "Project HamLog = SQLite raised exception class PDOException with message "SQLSTAT[HY000][14] unable to open database file at test.php, line 12".  The next executable line is $errorlevel=error_reporting();" that reports nothing because the debugger stops with a 255 undefined error.

Comment: I have now implemented the try/catch pair and no longer have the script stop.  I have verified the path is correct.  The same database can be opened in phpLiteAdmin.php, so I don't think it's a permissions problem, or a path problem.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: Try to put your sqlite file beside your php file and address it relatively. Maybe it's because of the path.

Comment: Problem is fixed.  Turned out to be a file naming error. Duh!